# How can I prevent a user from selecting multiple checkboxes in HTML?

Tags: html, checkbox

How can I prevent a user from selecting multiple checkboxes in HTML?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  A checkbox doesn't really have "multiple selection."  It's a single element with two possible states, checked or unchecked.  Maybe you're looking for radio buttons?

Comment: By using Radio buttons instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should change it to radio button instead of check box!

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item1" value="Milk">
<label for="item1">Milk</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item2" value="Butter" checked>
<label for="item2">Butter</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="item3" value="Cheese">
<label for="item13">Cheese</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a use case where I needed use checkboxes--which, unlike radio buttons, allows a user to UNcheck... Here's an example of something I pieced together from another stackoverflow user:

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>and-or checkboxes</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <label for="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="and" </label><span id="span_and">checkbox1</span><br>

    <label for="checkbox2"> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"  name="checkbox2"  value="or" </label><span id="span_or">checkbox2</span>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
            var checkedBox = $(this).attr("checked");
                if (checkedBox === true) {
                    $("#checkbox2").attr('checked', false);
                } else {
                    $("#checkbox2").removeAttr('checked');                    
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#checkbox2').click(function() {
            var checkedBox = $(this).attr("checked");
                if (checkedBox === true) {
                    $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', false);                     
                } else {
                    $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked');                       
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

With a little work, you can combine the either/or two scripts into a single script. You probably don't need this now but I wanted to post it because it was very useful to me.

Comment: Why would you make a selector for every checkbox? Use one selector that works for all! :)

Comment: what if there are more than 2 checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that only one checkbox get selected at a time then its better to use `radiobutton` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you don't want multiple checkboxes from a same "logical group" to be checked at one time, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="aGroup" value="choice1" /> Choice #1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="aGroup" value="choice2" /> Choice #2
</form>
```

By using this, only 1 option can be checked at one time

Answer (score 0):

Use Radio, and they must have the same `name=""`.