# HTML Grid Table single row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have HTMP Page, On that page we have button, when any user clicks on the button, it will open the pop-up window, which is having grid table. This html grid table has four columns.
those are: -

checkbox
Full name
Email ID
Emp ID

What I am trying to achieve here is that User should not be able to select more than one row on html grid table.

Please suggest some jQuery or JavaScript solution here, I cannot use any jQuery library here, I need to write some custom jQuery code, please help.

Thank You,
Ketan

I tried to search on the stack over flow for similar problem ,I did not find any thing

Comment: _User should not be able to select more than one row_ - "select" as in highlight text for copy paste?

Comment: Do you mean select using the checkbox? Why not use a radiobutton instead? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677933/2064588